# How do you order a group of records then insert their order placement too?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of logs that contain a ID and TIMESTAMP. I want to ORDER BY ID and then TIMESTAMP.

For example, this is what the result set would look like:

```
12345   05:40   
12345   05:50   
12345   06:22   
12345   07:55   
12345   08:33
```

Once that's done, I want to INSERT a order value in a third column that signifies it's placement in the group from earliest to latest.

So, you would have something like this:

```
12345   05:40   1 <---First entry
12345   05:50   2
12345   06:22   3
12345   07:55   4
12345   08:33   5 <---Last entry
```

How can I do that in a SQL statement? I can select the data and ORDER BY ID, TIMESTAMP. But, I can't seem to INSERT a order value based on the groupings. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `update` *not an* `insert`:

**[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5aecb/3)**:

```
;with cte as(
  select id, yourdate, row_number() over(order by id,yourdate) rn
  from yourTable
)
Update ut Set thirdCol = rn
From yourTable ut join cte on ut.Id = cte.id and ut.yourdate = cte.yourdate
```

**NOTE:** if you need to get the `thirdColumn` updated per id basis, please partition your rownumber by using `row_number() over (partition by id, order by order by id,yourdate)`

Results:

```
|    ID | YOURDATE | THIRDCOL |
|-------|----------|----------|
| 12345 |    05:40 |        1 |
| 12345 |    05:50 |        2 |
| 12345 |    06:22 |        3 |
| 12345 |    07:55 |        4 |
| 12345 |    08:33 |        5 |
```

Comment: Thanks. ROW_NUMBER() OVER() was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using a derived table and an update.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end


CREATE TABLE #TableOne
( 
SomeColumnA int , 
LetterOfAlphabet varchar(12) , 
PositionOrdinal int not null default 0 
)




INSERT INTO #TableOne ( SomeColumnA , LetterOfAlphabet )
select 123 , 'x'
union all select 123  , 'b'
union all select 123  , 'z'
union all select 123  , 't'
union all select 123  , 'c'
union all select 123  , 'd'
union all select 123  , 'e'
union all select 123  , 'a'

Select 'pre' as SpaceTimeContinium , * from #TableOne order by LetterOfAlphabet

Update 
#TableOne
Set PositionOrdinal = derived1.rowid
From 
( select SomeColumnA , LetterOfAlphabet , rowid = row_number() over (order by LetterOfAlphabet asc)  from #TableOne innerT1  ) 
as derived1
join #TableOne t1
    on t1.LetterOfAlphabet = derived1.LetterOfAlphabet and t1.SomeColumnA = derived1.SomeColumnA


Select 'post' as SpaceTimeContinium, * from #TableOne order by LetterOfAlphabet


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the order you desire *without doing an insert and an update*, you can set your clustered index to handle it for you.  The example below creates a clustered primary key.

To do this you must remove any clustered index that you already have on the table because you can only have one clustered index per table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
(
ID int NOT NULL,
DTStamp datetime NOT NULL
) 


ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT
PK_Table_1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
ID,
DTStamp
)
```

Insert some random data to test with...

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12346,getdate());
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12346,dateadd(mi,1,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12346,dateadd(mi,2,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12346,dateadd(mi,3,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12346,dateadd(mi,4,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12340,dateadd(mi,5,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12340,dateadd(mi,6,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12340,dateadd(mi,7,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12340,dateadd(mi,8,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12344,dateadd(mi,1,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12344,dateadd(mi,2,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12344,dateadd(mi,3,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12344,dateadd(mi,4,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12344,dateadd(mi,5,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12344,dateadd(mi,6,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12344,dateadd(mi,7,getdate()));
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([ID],[DTStamp])VALUES(12344,dateadd(mi,8,getdate()));
```

Now query your table and check out the order...

```
SELECT  [ID] ,[DTStamp]  FROM [Table_1]
```

If you need the order to display in a query, you can add the row number with an over clause.

```
SELECT  [ID] ,[DTStamp],row_number() over (partition by [ID] order by [ID] ,[DTStamp]) as SortOdr FROM [Table_1]
```